# How do I add a table of contents line that isn't numbered?

Tags: table-of-contents

When I add a section, the table of contents automatically reads the page number and inputs it into the table of contents. Is there a way to add a line in the table of contents that excludes the page number of the section?

And if I were to add a table of contents line for a subsection, is there a way to remove the dots following the section name? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Answers to your questions depend importantly on which document class is employed. Please tell us more about your document setup. In particular, do mention if you load any packages, such as `tocloft`, which affect the appearance of the table of contents. Moreover, please clarify whether the section header in question is numbered or unnumbered (as apart from being associated with a page number).

Comment: Should there be only one section entry without page number? And the subsections: all without dots between the entry and the page number or only one special subsection?

Comment: I didn't load any other packages that affect the table of contents except for hyperref. And for my purposes, I would like to know how to disable page numbers for exactly one section entry, but it would be nice to know how to disable page numbers for an arbitrary number of entries in the table of contents. For the dots, I'm interested in both: one special subsection or all subsections.